# Instalação do SQLITE3 via NPM encontra 3 vulnerabilidade

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, sqlite3

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou tentando instalar o sqlite3 com o npm, e ao fim da instalação é informado que teve 3 vulnerabilidades. Fiz algumas pesquisas e gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O NPM tem uma versão desatualizada do sqlite3. É possível obter a última versão diretamente do Github com este comando:

```
npm install git@github.com:mapbox/node-sqlite3.git
```